# How to access parent modules when doing layered routing in mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

As a personal project, I'm trying to build a social media site for teddy bear collectors. I would like users to be able to make a "collection" page which they can populate with individual profile pages for each of their bears. Finally, I would like other users to be able to comment on both the collection page and the individual profile pages.

However, I'm running into an error on the "/new" route for comments on the individual profile pages. I can't get it to find the id for the parent collection.

Below is the code I'm working with. I start by finding the id for the collection, then I get try to get the id for the bear (individual profile page). However, the process keeps getting caught at the first step.

```
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router({mergeParams: true});
var Bear = require("../models/bear");
var Comment = require("../models/comment");
var Collection = require("../models/collection");
var middleware = require("../middleware");

//comments new
router.get("/new", middleware.isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
    Collection.findById(req.params.id, function(err, foundCollection) {
        if(err || !foundCollection){
            req.flash("error", "Collection not found");
            return res.redirect("back");
        }
        Bear.findById(req.params.bear_id, function(err, foundBear) {
            if(err){
                res.redirect("back");
            } else {
                res.render("bcomments/new", {collection_id: req.params.id, bear: foundBear, collection: foundCollection});
            }
        });
    });
});

//bcomments create
router.post("/", middleware.isLoggedIn, function(req, res){
    Collection.findById(req.params.id, function(err, foundCollection) {
        if(err || !foundCollection){
            req.flash("error", "Collection not found");
            return res.redirect("back");
        }
        //look up bear using id
        Bear.findById(req.params.id, function(err, foundBear){
        if(err){
             console.log(err);
             res.redirect("/bears" + bear._id);
        } else {
            //create new comment
            Comment.create(req.body.comment, function(err, comment){
                if(err){
                    req.flash("error", "Something went wrong");
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    //add username and id to comment
                    comment.author.id = req.user._id;
                    comment.author.username = req.user.username;
                    //save comment
                    comment.save();
                    //connect new comment to bear
                    bear.comments.push(comment);
                    bear.save();
                    //redirect bear show page
                    req.flash("success", "Successfully added comment");
                    res.redirect("/collections/" + foundCollection._id + "/bears/" + foundBear._id);
                    }
                 });
             }
         });
     });    
 });
```

So, instead of rendering the new comment form, it hits a "null" error and redirects back at the first if statement.

If anyone can help me figure this out, I'd be exceedingly grateful.
Thank you.

Comment: For HTTP request sent to `/new`, how did you pass the id of collection?

Comment: Man, that was half the problem! I was passing both the collection id and bear id as ":id" app.use("/collections/:id/bears/:id/bcomments", bcommentRoutes);
but after updating the path it works: app.use("/collections/:id/bears/:bear_id/bcomments", bcommentRoutes);

Thank you so much for your help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are defining the path "/new" (which has no parameters) and trying to access `req.params.id`. If you expect to have the parameter `id` you should define it in the path like this: `router.get("/new/:id", ...`. Check the Express [oficial documentation](https://expressjs.com/es/api.html#req.params) for more details.

EDIT:

You may have mixed `req.params` with `req.query` and `req.body`. If you are passing parameters in the request, you must access them through `req.query` (for example: `req.query.id` or `req.query.bear_id`) in the case of GET and DELETE or through `req.body` in POST and PUT.

Comment: Ah, yeah, that was half the problem! I had forgotten to pass the bear_id.
Also, in the app.js file I had both the collection id and bear id using the same parameter name in the path.

Thank you so much for your help!! :D I'm so happy to have this figured out now.